# How to feed output of GPUImage rawDataOutput to OpenCV findCountours function

Tags: opencv, ios7, gpuimage

Currently I have the following:

[cameraFeed] -> [gaussianBlur] -> [sobel] -> [luminanceThreshold] -> [rawDataOutput]

the rawDataOuput I would like to pass it to the OpenCV findCountours function. Unfortunately, I can't figure out the right way to do this. The following is the callback block that gets the rawDataOuput and that should pass it to the OpenCV function but it does not work. I am assuming there are a few things involved such as converting the BGRA image given by GPUImage to CV_8UC1 (single channel) but I am not able to figure them out. Some help would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
    // Callback on raw data output
    __weak GPUImageRawDataOutput *weakOutput = rawDataOutput;
    [rawDataOutput setNewFrameAvailableBlock:^{
        [weakOutput lockFramebufferForReading];
        GLubyte *outputBytes = [weakOutput rawBytesForImage];
        NSInteger bytesPerRow = [weakOutput bytesPerRowInOutput];
        // OpenCV stuff
        int width = videoSize.width;
        int height = videoSize.height;
        size_t step = bytesPerRow;
        cv::Mat mat(height, width, CV_8UC1, outputBytes, step); // outputBytes should be converted to type CV_8UC1
        cv::Mat workingCopy = mat.clone();

        // PASS mat TO OPENCV FUNCTION!!!

        [weakOutput unlockFramebufferAfterReading];
        // Update rawDataInput if we want to display the result
        [rawDataInput updateDataFromBytes:outputBytes size:videoSize];
        [rawDataInput processData];
    }];
```

Comment: "Does not work" is never descriptive enough. What happens, and what is your expected result? What are the debugging steps you've tried so far? What does every intermediary stage provide you?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. When I say "does not work" I mean that I get the wrong number of contours detected. Now, keep in mind that the openCV code is correct since it works fine on a different version of the app that does not use GPUImage.
One solution I found was to use cv::cvtColor() to convert the outputBytes which have 4 channels to a single channel CV_8UC1 by using BGRA2GRAY. I would have liked though to do this directly in  GPUImage given that GPUImage already has a filter to convert to grayscale and perhaps is faster. Any suggestions on how to do it in GPUImage? Thanks.

Comment: The RGB to Gray done by GPUImage leaves the pixels in the standard interlaced format RGBARGBARGBA. The best way to get them into OpenCV is simply copy out every 4th pixel to a new GLubyte array of the appropriate size. Most compilers will be able to optimize this to use their onboard SIMD and thus the performance hit is negligible. You can then wrap this new array in cv::Mat.

Answer (score 0):

Try change CV_8UC1 to CV_8UC4 and then convert to gray.
In code replace lines

```
cv::Mat mat(height, width, CV_8UC1, outputBytes, step);
cv::Mat workingCopy = mat.clone();
```

with

```
cv::Mat mat(height, width, CV_8UC4, outputBytes, step);
cv::Mat workingCopy;
cv::cvtColor(mat, workingCopy, CV_RGBA2GRAY);
```